# GML Alarm event not working second time

Tags: gml

I have my game setup so that it starts and goes back to a loading screen room for 45 steps after which the next room is randomized. So at alarm[0] the following code activates:

```
randomize();
chosenRoom = choose(rm_roomOne, rm_roomTwo, rm_roomThree, rm_roomFour);
room_goto(chosenRoom);
```

The code here works fine the first time, but when it goes back from the randomly chosen room to the loading screen room it stays there and doesn't execute the code again.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How do you call the alarm[0] ? In what event do you start it?

Comment: I have simply added the alarm event in a control object. It sets alarm[0] at 45 in the create event and then in the alarm[0] event it executes the above piece of code (well only the first time). So it's pretty much loadingRoom -> execute code -> randomRoom -> loadingRoom -> stops

Answer (score 1):

This may sound stupid but did you remember to set the alarm again after it's gone off? I know I've done this several times without thinking. Without seeing your code, I assume that after the alarm goes off it's not being set again, so it won't go off again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the control object is "persistant", thus the Control Object only exists once and will remain forever (also after swithcing rooms) - thus thie create event only gets fired once - thus the alarm only gets set once.

Try to move your code to the event "Room Start" in your controller and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `event_perform(ev_alarm,0);`.
The code here performs alarm[0] after 45 steps. after 45 steps again it triggers alarm[0]. Note that you have to put it in step event. And you have to initialize wait variable and times to zero in create event.
`times` is the repeat and `wait` is distance between events.

```
if(wait == 45 && times !=2){
    event_perform(ev_alarm,0);
    times++;
    wait = 0; 
}
else{
    wait++;
}
```